# Match single value of multivalued daterange field

Tags: solr, solr6

Say I have a field defined in my schema and then indexed as 'dmvf_rab_date_range'

```
<fieldType name="date_range" class="solr.DateRangeField" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
<dynamicField name="dmvf_*" type="date_range" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

And then index a set of values such that they are returned like the following:

```
["[2018-04-07 TO 2018-04-07]",
 "[2018-04-14 TO 2018-04-27]",
 "[2018-05-05 TO 2018-05-05]",
 "[2018-11-03 TO 2018-11-16]",
 "[2018-11-24 TO 2019-01-04]"],
```

I'm trying to query such that I'll match a single value of the multivalued field or will fall completely in between a single value. But currently, my query just seems to see if it'll partially match in any of the values and return the document if that's the case.

Like if I query:

```
&fq=dmvf_rab_date_range:[2018-11-10 TO 2018-11-24]
```

That document will be returned even though it doesn't match or fall completely between a single value of the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default operator for DateRangeFields is `Intersects`. Since your query range intersects / overlaps with `[2018-11-03 TO 2018-11-16]`, you get a hit.

You can [set the operator through a localparam](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/working-with-dates.html#WorkingwithDates-MoreDateRangeFieldDetails):

```
&fq={!field f=dmvf_rab_date_range op=Contains}[2018-11-10 TO 2018-11-24]
```

This will give you a match if the indexed range contains the query range. You also have the operator `Within` - giving you ranges that fall within the query range (I wasn't completely sure which you wanted).